# C++ mutex and const correctness

Tags: c++

Is there convention regarding whenever method which is essentially read-only, but has mutex/ lock which may need to be modified, is const or not?

if there is not one, what would be disadvantage/bad design if such method is `const`

Thank you

Comment: I would argue that it depends on the semantics of the class:  in different cases, different approaches might make sense.

Comment: Why would you not want to make it const?

Comment: @Neil  I got impression that mutable should be avoided, but it seems like mutex is a good candidate to use it, so I wanted to hear if it's okay design

Comment: @aaa I use mutable in my own code quite frequently, so it has my seal of approval, for what that's worth :-)

Comment: @Neil thank you.  I am actually very interested in what other people do if I am not sure about something

Comment: @aaa: I think the key question to answer to decide whether `mutable` is Ok to use or not is: _"Does this piece of data represent the object's state_ __as visible from the user__?" If you answer this with _"Yes, it does"_, then making it `mutable` would be abusing `mutable`. If you answer with _"No, it doesn't"_, then `mutable` _might_ be acceptable.

Comment: See Herb Sutter's ["You don't know const and mutable"](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) talk for detailed discussion.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can mark data members with the keyword `mutable` to allow them to be modified in a constant member function, e.g.:

```
struct foo 
{
    mutable mutex foo_mutex;
    // ....
    void bar() const
    {
        auto_locker lock(foo_mutex);
        // ...
    }
};
```

Try to do this as little as possible because abusing `mutable` is evil.

Comment: thank you.  I guess the question is really about design rather than how to implement

Comment: aaa@ marking mutex data members as mutable is one of the times it's kind of acceptable use case because it doesn't represent the object's real state.

Comment: In our product, this keyword is used three times and one of the three is exactly `mutable boost::mutex`. Some day I'll figure out how to get rid of the other two.

Comment: thanks, that was my impression as well, but I was not sure if it's sound design

Comment: @aaa in our code base we also use mutable for mutex data members, another acceptable use-case would be reference counted objects I mean the actual reference count member. Another sort of acceptable use-case is lazily evaluated objects with "is_dirty" flags.

Answer (score 20):

I'm generally OK with `mutable` locks and caches for methods that are conceptually `const`.

Especially in the case of caching the result of a calculation for performance.  That's strictly an implementation detail that shouldn't be of concern to the callers, so removing the `const` designation would be tantamount to a small leak in the abstraction.

With locks, I'd ask myself if the lock is just a private implementation detail.  If the lock is shared with other objects, then it's actually part of the interface.

On some platforms, locks are accessed through handles, so you can use `const` on the method without worrying about `mutable`.