# How can map operations in one thread be done safely, without invalidate iterators in another?

Tags: c++, stl

I have two threads operating on a shared map. One thread (named thread 1) just keeps inserting pairs into the map. The other thread (named thread 2) keeps getting the map's first element, does some operation on the element, and finally erases it from the map. It doesn't matter to thread 2 whether the element it operates on happens to be at the map's beginning after thread 1 inserts an element. However, the map element in thread 2 must not be invalidated by thread 1's insert.

I know that STL containers are not thread-safe on their own, but they can still be quite useful if properly adapted. So my approach is every time thread 2 gets an element, I make a copy of the data and do my work. Also, map methods are made atomic by using a lock_guard on a mutex stored as a member.

pseudocode like below under c++17

```
my_map {
    insert(value_type value){
        lock_guard(mutex)
        map.insert(value)
    }
    erase(iterator position){
        lock_guard(mutex)
        map.erase(position)
    }
    end(){
        lock_guard(mutex)
        map.end()
    }
    begin(){
        lock_guard(mutex)
        map.begin()
    }
}
```

thread 1:

```
while(1){
    sleep(1)
    my_map.insert(random())
}
```

thread 2:

```
while(!my_map.empty()){
    auto it = my_map.begin()
    auto k = it->first;
    auto v = it->second;
    work(k, v);
    my_map.erase(it);
}
```

The locks should prevent the map itself from becoming invalid due to simultaneous mutation. My concern is how map operations might affect iterators and elements of the map. Consider this sequence:

[image: thread diagram]

What's the behavior if the sequence in the picture happens? That is to say, might the insertion in thread 1 invalidate `it`, `k` or `v` in thread 2 in some way (such as disturbing the iterator so `k` and `v` don't correspond, or destroying the iterator so `k` or `v` can't be retrieved)?

I was told using a copy of the map is thread-safe but it wouldn't be ok with the iterator, so it is correct? And how do I make the copy of one element in the map or some other STL containers to achieve thread safety?

Comment: Could you show us some code for the scenario you are asking about?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve].  Please post all necessary code as formatted text in the question.  Links can expire and make the question useless for future readers.  Images can not be copied and compiled into a working example / test case.

Comment: @RichardCritten Well, I post the address of my another question.. I just edit this page and paste the psuedocode

Comment: Assuming `my_map.empty()` is synchronized similarly to other methods, I believe this scenario is thread-safe. `insert` doesn't invalidate any iterators, and doesn't race with accessing an element through an existing iterator.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I believe that gives me the answer I want. Thanks a lot

Comment: For const methods and the map's mutex, check out "[C++ mutex and const correctness](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239905/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

### Insertion Affects on Thread 2's Iterators/References

For `std::map` and other ordered associative containers, insertion won't [invalidate container iterators (or element references)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Iterator_invalidation), so `it` (and `it->first` and `it-second`) in thread 2 shouldn't be affected by thread 1's `my_map.insert`. (Note: this is entirely due to the standard behavior for containers, not the locks. Though the locks ensure `my_map.insert(...)` in thread 1 and `my_map.begin()` and `my_map.erase(...)` won't overlap, they don't affect the interaction of the insertion in thread 1 and accessing through the iterator in thread 2.) It's a different story for the unordered containers, such as [`std::unordered_set`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/) and [`std::unordered_map`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/), which will invalidate iterators if they must rehash.

### Other Operation Affects on Thread 2's Iterators/References

Since thread 1's insertion won't affect `it->first` or `it->second`, making local copies isn't necessary. With the addition of a synchronized `my_map::extract` method (calling [`map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract), added by C++17), the extraction can be made atomic (as long as the element doesn't need to remain in the map while the work is done):

```
my_map::node_type my_map::extract(iterator position) {
    lock_guard<decltype(my_map::mutex)> lock(mutex);
    return map::extract(position);
}

void thread2() {
    while(! my_map.empty()){
        auto element = my_map.extract(my_map.begin())
        work(element.key(), element.value());
    }
}
```

If other threads were to remove elements from the map, however, it then would be necessary to ensure the data in thread 2 wasn't affected, as thread 2 could be interrupted between the calls to `my_map::begin` and `my_map::extract`, and an erasure might invalidate the passed iterator. That should be the only critical point in thread 2, as finding & removing the element from the map both early and atomically should ensure other threads won't be able to erase the node themselves (though thread 2 could affect iterators and references in other threads, which would need to be addressed in their own critical sections).

#### Protecting Against Erasure

A copy or extraction would need to be protected by e.g. locks to prevent an erasure from interrupting the operation; `my_map` has just such a lock. Looking at it from another angle, removing and returning the first element is entirely an operation on `my_map`, and is thus a candidate to be a method.

In other languages, this operation is called `pop` or `shift`. There are some similarly named [STL containers methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Member_function_table) (`pop_back` and `pop`), though they remove an element but don't return it, and `map` doesn't have such a method.  Let's call the method `shift`:

```
my_map::node_type my_map::shift() {
    lock_guard<decltype(my_map::mutex)> lock(mutex);
    return map::extract(map::begin());
}

void thread2() {
    while(! my_map.empty()){
        auto element = my_map.shift()
        work(element.key(), element.value());
    }
}
```

Note there are some caveats about the elements returned by `extract`:

> Pointers and references to the extracted element remain valid, but cannot be used while element is owned by a [node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) [`node_type`]: they become usable if the element is inserted into a container.

See "[std::unordered_map::extract references/pointers invalidation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52739158/90527)" for details, but the gist is you can access the data via the [`node_type::key()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle#key) and [`node_type::value()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle#value) methods (including assigning to them, which is why there's a caveat). The issue in general would be if other threads had a reference to the same element and it were modified via the node handle (which thread 2 doesn't do, but steps would still need to be taken for safety), it could cause issues in those other threads.

`shift` above is a bit leaky in its return value. This could be addressed by returning a value type instead:

```
my_map::value_type my_map::shift() {
    lock_guard<decltype(my_map::mutex)> lock(mutex);
    auto node = map::extract(map::begin());
    return value_type(std::move(node.key()), std::move(node.value()));
}

thread2() {
    while(! my_map.empty()){
        auto element = my_map.shift()
        work(element.first, element.second);
    }
}
```

Since `node_type::key()` and `node_type::value()` return lvalues, `std::move` in `my_map::shift` is used to convert these to rvalues, so that the returned pair grabs the data from the node, rather than making copies.

Alternatively, a lock could protect the call to `work` as a critical section, though this would be less performant if `work(...)` takes an appreciable amount of time. In general, copying/extracting reduces the critical section of code, so other threads don't need to wait for the real work to complete.

### Erasure Affects on Thread 1

As thread 1 doesn't operate on elements of the map (only the map itself), there's nothing for thread 2's `my_map.erase(...)` to affect in that regard. Even if thread 1 did operate on an iterator or reference to an item from `my_map`, the erase would only invalidate erased elements (thread 1 would need to protect against this, as described above).